Can I cut a 6" hole through a rim joist in a balloon framed home?
I have a (I think rim joist) going around a bump out, and I'd like to put a 6" hole in it to run ductwork to the outside. Is there any possibility that this could be a structural concern?
Other context: It's a 1900s house, bump out goes all the way to the basement and up through the second floor as well. The house is balloon framed. This rim joist is above a window (see pictures)
If I do this anything else I should do to help frame it?



1900 balloon framed house.  Close to my heart, as that's what my son has and I've spent some time working on his floor joists.  Anyway, in general, I don't think rim joists are structural in the sense that they carry vertical loads.  They mostly serve to tie the floor joists together, and to give you a good nailing surface.  And in my son's house, the wall studs (24' long) rest on the sill plate, and not on the first floor rafters.
